# How to modify if-else logic to in a script to retrieve data for T-14 days

Tags: python, scripting

I have an exsting script which is used to extract data for T and T-1 day. I tried to modify it extract two weeks data, but the script is not able to search the dates other than current date

Check the code section :

```py
def parse_gov():
    reject_patterns = generate_reject_patterns()

    today_str = date.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=14)
    yesterday_str = yesterday.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    #query_date = date.today()
    #query_date = yesterday

    query_last = '''select last sym, last source, last lastTimeStamp, last objectName...

    query_all = '''select objectName, IONrecType, sym, source, lastTimeStamp, objectName, ....

    def query(q, query_date):
        if query_date =  date.today() - timedelta(days=14):
            date_clause = "date <= {date}, ".format(date = query_date)
            kdbport = '1000' ( historical database)
        else:
            date_clause = ""
            kdbport = '1001' (current database)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **else** part is not triggering because the comparison is not happening over there.
you need to change 
`query_date =  date.today() - timedelta(days=14):`
to 
`query_date ==  (date.today() - timedelta(days=14)):`

You always use `==` for comparison, `=` will assign the value to the variable.

Comment: Thanks . It goes to the else section now.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this solved your issue. @Rajdeep

Comment: Sorry, I can't stop it: *your

Comment: The problem now is it is actually not retrieving 14 days worth of data which is my original requirement. I will check further on this.